# How to create a trigger to run a procedure at a certain time?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers, procedures

I need to know if there is any way to create trigger to execute procedure on certain time like :

```
create trigger Fire 
when sysdate = 1-oct-2015 
execute (procedure);
```

I hope you understand me and please provide any solution how I can do it

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's illegal to execute your producer

Comment: Thanks for the replay but please what you mean by that .

Comment: a producer is a person and execute also  means murder. i fixed your spelling though so it doesn't look like you're trying too kill people.

Comment: you are right thanks for mention :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Trigger](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/create_trigger.htm) is executed *BEFORE* or *AFTER* some event e.g. INSERT. To control execution at a specific time maybe you need a [SCHEDULER](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/schedadmin006.htm#i1009099)

Simple example is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13859115/how-to-schedule-a-job-to-run-twice-a-day-using-dbms-scheduler) other search with "DBMS_SCHEDULER"

Comment: Thanks so much This Helped a lot one more thing can you tell me how to monitor it if it run successful or not and why

Comment: Have a look at the system views that show the status of the scheduled job, and its execution history. You can also use scheduler chains to get custom actions (such as sending an email) when a job completes successfully or unsuccessfully.

Answer (score 1):

There are various ways to schedule a PROCEDURE/FUNCTION. Below are the mentioned ways you can do it.

```
1) There is DB scheduler.
2) There is CRON TAB.
3) There is AUTOSYS jobs.
4) Datawarehousing tools like ETL (Informatica etc.)

These are very eficient to handle these kind of scheduling. My personal favourite id AUTOSYS jobs which uses.JIL file.
Let me know if this helps you.
:)
```